# Web scraping in python returns []

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am new to python web scraping.

I am trying to make a program that scrapes domain names and their values from the GoDaddy domain registrar. However, when attempting to obtain the domain name the value returned is [].

```
url = 'https://uk.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&domainToCheck=rocket'

response = requests.get(url)

if not response.ok:
    print('The server responded:', response.status_code)
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

domain = soup.find_all('span',class_="domain-name-text h4 text-bold")

print(domain)
```

This is the HTML segment which contains the data I need:

```
<span data-cy="spin-results-wrap-domain-name" dir="ltr">
<span class="domain-name-text h4 text-bold">rockethub</span>
<span class="domain-name-text h4 text-bold domain-name-tld">.</span>
<span class="domain-name-text h4 text-bold domain-name-tld">co</span>
</span>
```

All of the necessary packages are installed:bs4,lxml and requests.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the HTML or is it from the browser DOM?

Comment: This page using javascript to load the data. Maybe, you are looking for api. If you open the dev-tools -> Network -> XHR you will see the contents. `https://uk.godaddy.com/domainfind/v1/search/spins?&q=rocket&pagestart=0&pagesize=40&tld_gallery_size=5&key=dpp_search&tlds=&source=&maxsld=&pc=&ptl=&itc=dpp_absol1&req_id=1599913966766`. This is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like GoDaddy.com renders its web pages via JavaScript and the requests package does not have the functionality to load JavaScript.

Perhaps look at the library [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Its a headless web browser and will render the JavaScript for you, meaning it will load the domain names you're attempting to scrape.

Selenium code snippet:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # You will be required to setup a chrome driver.

driver.get('https://uk.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&domainToCheck=rocket')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "spin-results-wrap"))
    ) # You need to wait for the webpage to render the domains (its an asynchronous web request made).
except TimeoutException:
    raise

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") # Also note I use the html.parser instead of lxml.

domain = soup.find_all('span', class_="domain-name-text h4 text-bold")

print(domain)
```

Here's a good tutorial on how to setup ChromeDriver for Selenium: [link](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/chromedriver-selenium/.).

Comment: Hi, Shane I tried it your way and it still resulted in [].

Comment: @StrangeGamer Hey, I updated the code to fix the bug. That should do the trick. I tested it myself and it works. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of usage, I recommend you to use selenium, in my opinion it's much more simple to use.
Selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path/to/your/chromedriver')
driver.get(your_url)
domain = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_of_the_element)
#domain = class.WebElement--> domain.text to retrieve the string.
```

To download the chromedriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads